# Cracks in plaster

Tags: plaster, cracks

Are these cracks a structural issue or just change of temperature?
They seem to become smaller in the cooler weather and more noticeable in warmer weather.[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are they?   We need a very zoomed out picture.

Comment: I'm guessing those are plaster walls not sheet rock and they are caused by the seasonal expansion of framing due to heat and humidity.

Comment: I zoomed in so you can see them, yes it is plaster. On an extension to the house.

Answer (score 1):

Those appear to be very tiny cracks and without some other evidence to suggest that there is some structural issue here, I'd say they are cosmetic.

Look for things like windows no longer opening or closing easily, doors not fitting in their frames properly, bulges in drywall, cracks that get wider as time passes.